# Clip all polygons inside the boundary of provinces to separate and calculate every inside polygons area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, features, masking, extract

I need to calculate area of polygons inside every province but some of polygons are not exactly inside of one province and part of it is in one province and the other part is in another province. How can I divide these such polygons with boundary of provinces to have two or more closed polygon in each related province to calculate all polygons area for every province.

Comment: Have you tried to Intersect the sources?  There could be sliver polygons to resolve (and potentially an extra pass of Repair Geometry).